# SSL certificates not loaded and container startup

Tags: ssl, docker, ssl-certificate

I have a container from where I am trying to reach an HTTPS URL using:

> curl -v https//myserver:7050

The SSL issuer certificate of the server is placed on the VM where I run the container in /etc/ssl/certs. This VM location is volume mapped to /etc/ssl/certs of the container. This means the cert should be available to the container.
However, when I issue the curl command, I get a message saying "unable to get issuer certificate".

Then I need to run

> update-ca-certificates --refresh

After this the curl command succeeds.

If I am starting the container with a volume map, why am I required to run the update-ca-certificates command? Shouldn't the container already have all the certs in its cache when it starts up?

Regards
Yash

Answer (score 0):

Files on `/etc/ssl/certs` are symlinks to other files, if you mount a folder with symlinks, it will try to load the files they are linked, which probally doesnt exists inside your container.

U will need to mount the original file locations too.

```
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   49 Jul 19 06:51 ca-bundle.crt -> /etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/pem/tls-ca-bundle.pem
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   55 Jul 19 06:51 ca-bundle.trust.crt -> /etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/openssl/ca-bundle.trust.crt
```

Or you can mount the original single files to your container /etc/ssl/certs

Comment: The original folder /etc/ssl/certs itself is mounted to /etc/ssl/certs in the container. The certs of my server are physically present in the VM's /etc/ssl/certs folder. In that case it should work.